# How to insert \n character in MySQL table from PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, linefeed

I am trying a few hours now to add the character \n in a MySQL table. I have a form. If someone presses OK with no data given i want to pass in the table tha character \n.

I have tried this.

```
$null_value = '\n';
$null_value = mysql_real_escape_string($null_value);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (x,x) VALUES ('$null_value','$null_value');
```

But nothing happened. I would appreciate it if someone can help me out with this ?

Comment: do you want to add /n as a string or newline?

Comment: Are you sure your table name and column names are correct? For debugging purposes, you can try using `echo mysql_error();` after your `mysql_query()` to see if MySQL returns an error.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to insert `\n` as new line, use double quotes `"` not single quote `'`

```
$null_value = "\n";
```

Comment: Correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply put a new line in your string, don't use `\n` escape sequence as

```
INSERT INTO `person`(`id`, `name`) VALUES (11,"
                                       ")
```

In your case

```
$null_value = '
';
$null_value = mysql_real_escape_string($null_value);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (x,x) VALUES ('$null_value','$null_value');
```

Comment: I want to add the \n character, because afterwards i replace it with <br/> when echoing the results

Comment: If you want to add "\n" as character then use like this "\\n", if you want to store a next line character then use the above syntax

Answer (score 0):

I would to thank everyone for your answers. The problem has been solved. I had an error in my IF Statement. I followed the answer with the addslashes().

Thanks again !